# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers then the roots of $x^2+\alpha x+\beta$ are algebraic integers

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory

(This question is a dupplicate from [If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers then any solution to $x^2+\alpha x + \beta = 0$ is also an algebraic integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550926/if-alpha-and-beta-are-algebraic-integers-then-any-solution-to-x2-alpha))

I'm trying to solve this problem with my current knowledge of algebraic integers:

- $x$ is an algebraic integer if it is a root of a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$
- $x$ is an algebraic integer iff $xW\subset W$ for some finitely generated free $\mathbb Z$-module $W$ (i.e. $W$ has a finite basis).

My first thought was to try Hurkyl's answer and compute
$$
\prod_i\prod_j x^2+\alpha_ix+\beta_j
$$
where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ are all the (complex) roots of the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but I couldn't show that it has integer coefficients. (Although I found that $\prod_j x^2+\alpha x+\beta_j=p_\beta(-x^2-\alpha x)$ where $p_\beta$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$.)

Today my teacher gave me as hint to take a smartly chosen $\mathbb Z$-module and use the second definition given above. However I don't see which one...

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What about $\;\Bbb Z[\alpha,\beta]\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio then $x^2\in\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]$ but does $x$ also lie in this module?

Comment: (edit: no, in fact $x^2$ wouldn't be in $\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]$ if $x$ isn't.)

Comment: Have you tried $W=\Bbb{Z}[x,\alpha,\beta]=\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]+x\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just thought of it but then I still have to prove that $x^2$, $\alpha x$ and $\beta x$ lie in $\mathbb Z[x,\alpha,\beta]$. Maybe $\mathbb Z[x,\alpha,\beta,\alpha x,\beta x]$? or maybe the module generated by all the cross products between $x_1$, $x_2$, $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k$? ($x_i$, $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ being all the roots of their respective polynomials)

Comment: $x^2$ and the like are in ${\mathbb Z}[x,\alpha,\beta]$: it is generated (as a ${\mathbb Z}$-algebra) by $x$, $\alpha$, $\beta$. What you do have to argue, though, is that ${\mathbb Z}[x,\alpha,\beta]$ is free (as a ${\mathbb Z}$-module) (which @JyrkiLahtonen just did in his updated comment).

Comment: @Magdiragdag then I may have a wrong definition in head… For a module $M$, $x\pm y\in M$ for every $x,y\in M$ but not necessarily $xy$, or? And $\mathbb Z[x,\alpha,\beta]=\{mx+n\alpha+p\beta\,|\,m,n,p\in\mathbb Z\}$, right?

By the way, how could I check that $\mathbb Z[x,\alpha,\beta]$ is free?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why is $\mathbb Z[x,\alpha,\beta]=\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]+x\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]$? If these modules are equal then yeah obviously $x^2=-\beta-x\alpha\in Z[\alpha,\beta]+x\mathbb Z[\alpha,\beta]$ and the same for $\alpha x$ and $\beta x$.

Comment: You're right in that a *module* doesn't have to be closed under multiplication, but ${\mathbb Z}[x,\alpha,\beta]$ is the smallest *algebra* containing $x, \alpha, \beta$. So that is closed under multiplication and it is not equal to the module $x{\mathbb Z} + \alpha{\mathbb Z} + \beta{\mathbb Z}$. To check that ${\mathbb Z}[x,\alpha,\beta]$ is free: find a basis (and use that ${\mathbb Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is a free module; you'll also need $x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0$.).

Comment: @Magdiragdag so the second definition of an algebraic integer should be: $x$ is an algebraic integer if there is a $\Bbb Z$-_algebra_ (and not module) $W$ such that $xW\subset W$?

Comment: For all $i,j$ we have $x\alpha^i\beta^j\in x\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$, and $x(x\alpha^i\beta^j)=x\alpha^{i+1}\beta^j+\alpha^i\beta^{j+1}\in \Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]+x\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$. By the assumption on $\alpha,\beta$ being algebraic we know that $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is a spanned by finitely many products of the form $\alpha^i\beta^j$, so that does it.

Comment: It should be "finitely generated ${\mathbb Z}$-algebra that is finite (free and with finite basis) as a ${\mathbb Z}$-module".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just got it with your last comment. Thanks!