# Algebraic integers: Explicit proof that $\prod_{i,j} (x^2+\alpha_i x+\beta_j)$ (with $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ conjugates) has integer coefficients.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-functions

An algebraic integer is a complex number that is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. In Exercise 3 of Chapter 6 of Ireland and Rosen's book on number theory, we are asked to show that if $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic integers, then any solution $x_0$ to the polynomial equation $x^2 +\alpha x + \beta$ is also an algebraic integers. This question was also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550926/if-alpha-and-beta-are-algebraic-integers-then-any-solution-to-x2-alpha?rq=1), though I'm struggling to fill out the details of user14972's answer, and I'd like some help filling out the details (or a pointer to a better path to take).

****Outline of solution:****

Expanding on user14972's answer, let $$f_\alpha(x) = x^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \ldots + a_0$$ be a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for which $\alpha$ is a root, and let $$f_\beta(x) = x^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + b_0$$ be a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for which $\beta$ is a root. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we may write
$$f_\alpha(x) = \prod_{i=1}^m(x-\alpha_i) ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ f_\beta(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n ( x-\beta_j)$$
for some $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ and $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m$ in $\mathbb{C}$. One of the $\alpha_i$ is equal to $\alpha$, and likewise one of the $\beta_j$ is equal to $\beta$.
$g(x)$ is plainly monic. user14972 claims that $g(x)$ has integer coefficients - it is this step that I am struggling to prove.

****Attempt to prove $g(x)$ has integer coefficients:****

We now show that $g(x)$ has integer coefficients. A brief calculation tells us that
$$g(x) = (-1)^n \prod_{i=1}^m f_\beta( - x^2 - \alpha_i x).$$
With $b_n =1$ we have
$$g(x) = (-1)^n \prod_{i=1}^m \sum_{ j_i = 0}^n b_{j} ( -x^2 - \alpha_i x)^{j} = (-1)^n \prod_{i=1}^m \sum_{0 \leq j_1,\ldots,j_m \leq n} (-x)^{j_1+\ldots+j_m} \prod_{i=1}^m b_{j_i} ( x+ \alpha_i)^{j_i}.$$
Let $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m)$ where $\lambda_1 \geq \ldots \geq \lambda_m \geq 0$ be decreasing integers. Write $|\lambda|$ for their sum. Write
\begin{align*}
m_\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_m) := \sum'_{ j_1,\ldots,j_m } x^{j_1} \ldots x^{j_m}
\end{align*}
where $\sum'_{ j_1,\ldots,j_m }$ denotes the sum is over all distinct orderings $(j_1,\ldots,j_m)$ of $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m)$. Then picking up from our last equation for $g(x)$, we have
$$g(x) =  (-1)^n \sum_{\lambda} (-x)^{|\lambda|} (\prod_{i=1}^m b_{\lambda_i} )m_\lambda(x+\alpha_1,\ldots,x+\alpha_m).$$

Now my suspicion is that $m_\lambda(x+\alpha_1,\ldots,x+\alpha_m)$ always has integer coefficients as a polynomial in $x$, but I'm not sure how to prove this. We know it is the case for $\lambda = (1,\ldots,1)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can just use the theorem on symmetric polynomials to conclude that $g(x) $ has integer coefficients.